# Como exibir DIV se o radio estiver marcado?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```html
<form>
   <input type="radio" id="div1" name="consulta[]" value="1">Opção 1
   <input type="radio" id="div2" name="consulta[]" value="2">Opção 2
   <input type="submit" value="Registrar"> 
</form>
<div id="m1" style="display:none">
    DIV 1
</div>
<div id="m2" style="display:none">
    DIV 2
</div>
```

Preciso que a DIV 1 só apareça (alterando seu display no css) quando o radio div1 estiver clicada, e o mesmo para a DIV 2.

Qual a forma mais simples de fazer isso?

Comment: você está utilizando algum framework que tem classes auxiliares como "hidden" ?

Comment: uso o jquery-3.2.1, mas não sei dizer quais as classes ele oculta

Comment: Quis dizer bootstrap.. materialize

Comment: nao. nao uso nenhum framework deste tipo

Comment: Já testou a função checked? Ficaria assim:     if(document.getElementById('div1').checked) {
      <div id="m1" style="display:none">
        DIV 1
      </div>
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('input:radio[name="consulta"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
          $("#m1").attr("hidden", false);
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
          
          $("#m2").attr("hidden", true);
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
          
        } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
          $("#m2").attr("hidden", false);
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
          
          $("#m1").attr("hidden", true);
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="radio" id="div1" name="consulta" checked value="1">Opção 1
   <input type="radio" id="div2" name="consulta" value="2">Opção 2
   <input type="submit" value="Registrar"> 
</form>
<div id="m1">
    DIV 1
</div>
<div id="m2" hidden>
    DIV 2
</div>
```

Um solução simples é utilizar o método `change()` do *jQuery*, toda vez que houver um evento em um *input* `radio`, o método change() será chamado.

Comment: A solução resolve, mas não é escalonável, só uma observação.

Answer (score 2):

Se você alterar a estrutura do HTML e colocar os `<div>` dentro do formulário, após os inputs, pode fazer esse efeito de toggle somente com CSS. [Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139763/4056678) uma explicação sobre o seletor `+`.

```css
form div {
  display: none;
  color: red
}

input[type='radio']:checked + div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for='div1'>Opção 1</label>
  <input type='radio' id='div1' name='consulta[]' value='1'>
  <div id='m1'>
    DIV 1
  </div>
  
  <label for='div2'>Opção 2</label>
  <input type='radio' id='div2' name='consulta[]' value='2'>
  <div id='m2'>
    DIV 2
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Quase isso. A resposta é excelente. Mas eu preciso que as duas divs em questão ocupem o mesmo espaço dentro da minha pagina. Só que dependendo do radio que for marcado, isso determinará qual div vai aparecer. Tentei adaptar o codigo para conseguir o que preciso mas não deu muito certo. Pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Usando jQuery, exitem várias formas de resolver seu problema, aqui eu listo uma:

```js
var viewDivs = {
  init: function(){
    var that = this;
    
    //Elements
    that.inputs = $('input:radio');
    that.divs = $('.div-radiobox');
    
    //Events
    that.inputs.change(function(){
        that.render();
    });
  },
  
  render: function(){
      //input selecionado
      var idDiv = this.inputs.filter(':checked').attr('data-div');
      
      this.divs.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.attr('id') == idDiv){
          $this.show();
          
        }else{
          $this.hide();
          
        }
     })
  }
}

viewDivs.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="radio" data-div="div1" name="consulta[]" value="1">Opção 1
   <input type="radio" data-div="div2" name="consulta[]" value="2">Opção 2
   <input type="submit" value="Registrar"> 
</form>
<div id="div1" class="div-radiobox" style="display:none">
    DIV 1
</div>
<div id="div2" class="div-radiobox" style="display:none">
    DIV 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao pé da letra creio que seja isso daqui...

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll(".rd");

for(let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    radio[i].onclick = function(){
       let div = document.querySelectorAll('.onOff');
       for(let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) div[i].style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('e' + radio[i].id).style.display = "block";
    } 
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="radio" id="div1" class="rd" name="consulta[]" value="1">Opção 1
   <input type="radio" id="div2" class="rd" name="consulta[]" value="2">Opção 2
   <input type="submit" value="Registrar"> 
</form>
<div id="ediv1" class="onOff" style="display:none">
    DIV 1
</div>
<div id="ediv2" class="onOff" style="display:none">
    DIV 2
</div>
```

Assim você pode adicionar mais inputs e referencia-los com uma `div`, basta adicionar o 'e' e o numero correspondente exemplo...

```
<input type="radio" id="div7" name="consulta" value="7">Opção 7

...

<div id="ediv7" class="onOff" style="display:none">
    DIV 7
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Porque não usas o atributo [hidden](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp)?

E podes testar [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/y4trcdsx/)

```
<form onchange="myFunction();">
  <label for='div1'>Opção 1</label>
  <input type='radio' id='div1' name='consulta[]'  value='1' >
  <div id='m1' hidden>
    DIV 1
  </div>

  <label for='div2'>Opção 2</label>
  <input type='radio' id='div2' name='consulta[]' value='2'>
  <div id='m2' hidden>
    DIV 2
  </div>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var $radio1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var $div1 = document.getElementById("m1");
    var $radio2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    var $div2 = document.getElementById("m2");
    if($radio1.checked){
        $div1.removeAttribute("hidden"); 
    }else{
        $div1.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
    }
    if($radio2.checked){
        $div2.removeAttribute("hidden"); 
    }else{
        $div2.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: por questões de estetica, o hidden faz com que o div continue na pagina, mesmo nao sendo exibido. o display:none faz com que ele só ocupe espaço na pagina caso o display seja alterado

Comment: ''é suposto''? desculpe, não entendi seu comentario

Comment: Segundo o teste que eu fiz o hidden não deixa o espaço em branco na página.

Comment: O div é completamente removido tanto que o radio2 fica ao lado do radio1 se o div1 estiver hidden apesar de continuar referido na página